# NexusOne AVD taking too long to start through Selenium

Tags: selenium, android-emulator, selendroid

To run my scripts on emulators I've configured an AVD with this configuration:

```
Target : `Google APIs(Google Inc.) API level 18`
Device: `Nexus One(3.7",480 x 800; hdpi)`
CPU : `ARM(armeabi-v7a)`
Hardware Keyboard present : `Yes`
Skin : `WVGA800`
RAM : `512`
VM Heap : `32`
Internal Storage : `200`
SD Card size: `1 GB`
USE GPU Host : `Yes`
Snapshot : `No`
```

It is taking too long to launch and sometimes it do not launch at all. Do I need to tweak something in settings?

I couldn't find any good reference on how to create AVDs where these parameters are explained with example.

Comment: Have you enabled the hardware acceleration?  This should speed up alot and might make it usable.  "Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) in the SDK installer.

Comment: Yeah I enabled that and it's still slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm now using Genymotion and it is far better in terms of consistency and speed.

Comment: Genymotion is better than other.